# Trying to implement DFS on a graph, which records discovered and finished time for all vertices. I get an "KeyError: False" as output. Also in python

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

```
 time = 0 # Initialize the gloabl time
    
    def DFS(graph):
        ### START YOUR CODE ###
        visited = [False] # Hint: a dict whose keys are all the vertices in the graph, and values are initialized to False
        discovered = [None] # Hint: same keys as above, values initialized to None
        finished = [None] # Hint: same as above
    vertex = 0

        ### END YOUR CODE ###
    
        global time # Make sure to use the global variable
        time = 0
        ### START YOUR CODE ###
        for u in graph.adj[vertex]: # Specify loop range
            if u not in visited:
                DFS_visit(graph, vertex, visited, discovered, finished)
            pass # Add necessary code
        ### END YOUR CODE ###
    
        return discovered, finished
    
    def DFS_visit(graph, vertex, visited, discovered, finished):
        ### START YOUR CODE ###
        global time
        time += 1
        discovered[vertex] = time
        pass # Add necessary code
        for v in graph.adj[vertex]: # Specify loop range
            if visited[v] == True:
                visited[v] = vertex
            else:
                DFS_visit(graph, vertex, visited, discovered, finished)
            pass # Add necessary code
    
            visited[vertex] += visited[v]
        time += 1
        finished = time
    
        pass # Add necessary code
        ### END YOUR CODE ###
```

This is what I have so far, but i get a KeyError: False. The time stamps are supposed to be stored in two dict objects, and the the vertices that have been visited are indicated by dict object whhos values are binary variables

Answer (score 0):

In your `DFS` method you set visited to False and then in the loop you use `graph.adj[visited]`. This results in keyerror because `False` is not in `graph.adj` dictionary.

You should have something like:

```
def DFS(graph):
    start_vertex = 0 # for example
    visited = set()
    ...
    for u in graph.adj[start_vertex]:
        if u not in visited:
    ...
```

Comment: ive fixed it, but im getting an eror that is saying KeyError:0

Comment: you have to adjust your start_vertex accordingly. How do you represent your graph? What does graph.adj return?